# Read an ImageURL Which Contains Query String - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have an image which can be replaced by uploading another image. I used the trick below to append a query string to image name so the browser load it as new image and show the uploaded one (a trick to bypass browsers image caching):

```
Image1.ImageUrl += "?" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmsskkk");
```

But there is a problem, when I try to read the new Image URL it gave me error that there illegal characters in image URL. How Can I clear the query string from image url each time I need to read it? or is there any way to remove the image cache?

Comment: If the query string parameter is properly formatted the values will be extracted for you. What does the url look like after you apend the timestamp?

Comment: We can't quite know what's wrong without knowing what the issue URL is, but I did notice that k isn't really a format parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx. See if you can remove the 'kkk' part, maybe including 'fff' instead (as I think that was the intent). Might help.